# can a manytomany relationship have two foreign keys in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, company and contract.  Each contract is between two companies.  Now, it seems there is a ManyToMany relationship between company and contract, e.g. a company can have many contracts and a contract is between more than one company.  Is this correct?  If yes, how to do you specify that in Django?  Is it through two foreign keys in one model?

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 30)

class Contract(models.Model):
    company_1 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company1")
    company_2 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company2")
    company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    contract_date = models.DateField()
    consideration = models.DecimalField(max_digit =10, decimal_places = 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a contract is just between two companies, then just remove this line. The mere fact that your Contract model has two different foreign key fields to Company already imply that a contract is between only two companies and each company may have multiple contracts accessible by using the respective related_name's.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    company_1 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company1")
    company_2 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company2")
    # company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    contract_date = models.DateField()
    consideration = models.DecimalField(max_digit =10, decimal_places = 2)
```

If, however, you want a contract involving more than two companies, then you remove the two foreignkeys and use a manytomany relationship like so. Similarly, this will automatically imply that a particular contract is shared by all companies listed under that relationship. You may access the contracts of a particular company via its related_name as well.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    # company_1 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company1")
    # company_2 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_company2")
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name=whatever_you_want)
    contract_date = models.DateField()
    consideration = models.DecimalField(max_digit =10, decimal_places = 2)
```

Comment: Ok! Please accept this answer if you have no more questions or clarifications for the benefit of others! Thanks!